# Nim: "invalid type ... in this context" error

Tags: types, compiler-errors, nim-lang

I'm trying to use Nim with Elm. Elm has a port system which can send and receive messages, similar to web workers.

I have this code in the main module:

```
import ./elm
import ./portMessages


type
    State = object
        elmProgram: elm.Program
        portToElm: elm.SubPort[portMessages.Outgoing]


# Error is with this function
proc newState(
    elmProgram: elm.Program,
): State =
    return State(
        elmProgram: elmProgram,
        portToElm: elmProgram.getSubPort("rawSubscribe"),
    )
```

When I try compiling, I get this error message from the compiler:

```
Error: invalid type: 'SubPort[SubPort.T]' in this context: 'proc (elmProgram: Program): State' for proc
```

This is the `elm` module. The `SubPort` type allows `T` to be sent through a port.

```
type
    Program* {.importjs.} = ref object of JsRoot
    SubPort*[T: JsRoot] {.importjs.} = ref object of JsRoot


# Get a reference to a Sub port (to Elm)
proc getSubPort*[T: JsRoot](
    program: Program,
    name: cstring,
): SubPort[T] {.importjs: "#.ports[#]".}
```

This is the 'portMessages' module:

```
type
    OutgoingKind* {.importjs.} = enum
        portErrorPopup = 0,
    
    Outgoing* {.importjs.} = ref object of JsRoot
        case kind*: OutgoingKind
        of portErrorPopup:
            msg*: cstring
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the type mismatch is because `getSubPort("messages")` is still an underspecified generic, as its returntype is `SubPort[T]`, which can't be inferred from its parameters.

meanwhile, you've specified that your `State` type's member `portToElm` has the type `SubPort[Outgoing]`

The answer should be as simple as:

```
proc newState(elmProgram: Program): State =
    State(
        elmProgram: elmProgram,
        portToElm: getSubPort[Outgoing](elmProgram,"rawSubscribe")
    )
```

but this still doesn't work because of a compiler [bug](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/7713).  The workaround is to use concepts for the generic restriction:

in `elm`:

```
type
  Program* {.importjs.} = ref object of JsRoot
  IsJsRoot = concept type t
    t is JsRoot
  SubPort*[T: IsJsRoot] {.importjs.} = ref object of JsRoot

proc getSubPort*[T:IsJsRoot](
    program: Program, name: cstring): SubPort[T]{.importjs: "#.ports[#]".}
```

(I don't understand why SubPort needs to be generic in the firstplace, especially as it's importjs, but that's beside the point)

Comment: I tried this and it still gives the same error

```
proc portToElm(
    state: State,
): elm.SubPort[portMessages.Outgoing] =
    return elm.getSubPort[portMessages.Outgoing](state.elmProgram, "rawSubscribe")
```

Comment: It's definitely not an issue with the body of `portToElm`. I replaced it with `raise newException(..)` and the error is exactly the same

Comment: you're right, i think that's a bug, edited my answer with a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Remove `: JsRoot` from the definition of the `SubPort` type:

```
type
    # ...
    SubPort*[T] {.importjs.} = ref object of JsRoot
```

It's also necessary to specify `portMessages.Outgoing` when calling `getSubPort`:

```
return State(
    # ...
    portToElm: elmProgram.getSubPort[: portMessages.Outgoing]("rawSubscribe"),
)
```